# Error #1010 in flash actionscript 3 preloader

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs5

I am trying to use a preloader to load a swf file and keep getting this error message.

```
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
at mpb_animated_rotator_fla::mc_main_holder_16/frame1()[mpb_animated_rotator_fla.mc_main_holder_16::frame1:36]
at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
at mpb_animated_rotator_fla::mc_starter_holder_1/frame10()[mpb_animated_rotator_fla.mc_starter_holder_1::frame10:1]
```

the movieclips in the main file have been exported to be accessed through actionscript. I am new to as3 and need help.

Preloader code

```
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
var myContent:URLRequest = new URLRequest("mpb_animated_rotator.swf");
var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();
var eContent_mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip(); 


myLoader.load(myContent);


myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);



function loadComplete(e:Event):void
{
myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);
guiding_loader.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loadingF);
function loadingF(e:Event):void{
    if (guiding_loader.ocean.currentFrame > 200){
        eContent_mc = MovieClip(myLoader.content);
        gotoAndStop(2);
        guiding_loader.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loadingF);
    }
}

}
```

main file code

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

var guiding:mc_guiding_complete = new mc_guiding_complete;
var innovation:mc_innovation_complete = new mc_innovation_complete;
var game:mc_game_change = new mc_game_change;
var yourb:mc_your_business_complete = new mc_your_business_complete;


addChild(guiding);
guiding.x = -215.20;
guiding.y = 230.25;
guiding.alpha = 0;
addChild(yourb);
yourb.x = 378;
yourb.y = 181;
yourb.alpha = 0;
addChild(game);
game.x = 377.95;
game.y = 181;
game.alpha = 0;
addChild(innovation);
innovation.x = 371.40;
innovation.y = 181;
innovation.innovate.gotoAndPlay(2);


innovation.innovate.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movetoGame);
game.chess.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movetoYourb);
yourb.industry.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movetoGuiding);
guiding.ocean.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movetoInnovation);

guiding.menu1.innovate_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, m1innovateClick);
guiding.menu1.game_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, m1gameClick);
guiding.menu1.yourb_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, m1yourbClick);
innovation.menu2.ocean_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, m2oceanClick);
innovation.menu2.game_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, m2gameClick);
innovation.menu2.yourb_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, m2yourbClick);
game.menu3.ocean_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, m3oceanClick);
game.menu3.innovate_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, m3innovateClick);
game.menu3.yourb_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, m3yourbClick);
yourb.menu4.ocean_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, m4oceanClick);
yourb.menu4.innovate_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, m4innovateClick);
yourb.menu4.game_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, m4gameClick);

function m1innovateClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
var guidingout2Tween:Tween = new Tween(guiding, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 1, 0, 1, true);
var innovationin2Tween:Tween = new Tween(innovation, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 0, 1, 1, true);
innovationin2Tween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, innovate2Play);
function innovate2Play (event:TweenEvent):void{
    innovation.innovate.gotoAndPlay(2);
    guiding.ocean.gotoAndStop(1);
    setChildIndex(innovation,4);
    setChildIndex(guiding,1);
    setChildIndex(yourb,2);
    setChildIndex(game,3);
}
}

function m1gameClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
var guidingout3Tween:Tween = new Tween(guiding, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 1, 0, 1, true);
var gamein2Tween:Tween = new Tween(game, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 0, 1, 1, true);
gamein2Tween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, game2Play);
function game2Play (event:TweenEvent):void{
    game.chess.gotoAndPlay(2);
    guiding.ocean.gotoAndStop(1);
    setChildIndex(innovation,1);
    setChildIndex(guiding,2);
    setChildIndex(yourb,3);
    setChildIndex(game,4);
}
}

function m1yourbClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
var guidingout4Tween:Tween = new Tween(guiding, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 1, 0, 1, true);
var yourbin2Tween:Tween = new Tween(yourb, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 0, 1, 1, true);
yourbin2Tween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, yourb2Play);
function yourb2Play (event:TweenEvent):void{
    guiding.ocean.gotoAndStop(1);
    yourb.industry.gotoAndPlay(2);
    setChildIndex(innovation,2);
    setChildIndex(guiding,3);
    setChildIndex(yourb,4);
    setChildIndex(game,1);
}
}

function m2oceanClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
var innovationout2Tween:Tween = new Tween(innovation, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 1, 0, 1, true);
var guidingin2Tween:Tween = new Tween(guiding, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 0, 1, 1, true);
guiding.ocean.gotoAndPlay(2);
guidingin2Tween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, guiding2Play);
function guiding2Play (event:TweenEvent):void{
    innovation.innovate.gotoAndStop(1);
    setChildIndex(innovation,3);
    setChildIndex(guiding,4);
    setChildIndex(yourb,1);
    setChildIndex(game,2);
}
}

function m2gameClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
var innovationout3Tween:Tween = new Tween(innovation, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 1, 0, 1, true);
var gamein3Tween:Tween = new Tween(game, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 0, 1, 1, true);
gamein3Tween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, game3Play);
function game3Play (event:TweenEvent):void{
    game.chess.gotoAndPlay(2);
    innovation.innovate.gotoAndStop(1);
    setChildIndex(innovation,1);
    setChildIndex(guiding,2);
    setChildIndex(yourb,3);
    setChildIndex(game,4);
}
}

function m2yourbClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
var innovationout4Tween:Tween = new Tween(innovation, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 1, 0, 1, true);
var yourbin3Tween:Tween = new Tween(yourb, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 0, 1, 1, true);
yourbin3Tween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, yourb3Play);
function yourb3Play (event:TweenEvent):void{
    innovation.innovate.gotoAndStop(1);
    yourb.industry.gotoAndPlay(2);
    setChildIndex(innovation,2);
    setChildIndex(guiding,3);
    setChildIndex(yourb,4);
    setChildIndex(game,1);
}
}

function m3oceanClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
var gameout2Tween:Tween = new Tween(game, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 1, 0, 1, true);
var guidingin3Tween:Tween = new Tween(guiding, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 0, 1, 1, true);
guiding.ocean.gotoAndPlay(2);
guidingin3Tween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, guiding3Play);
function guiding3Play (event:TweenEvent):void{
    game.chess..gotoAndStop(1);
    setChildIndex(innovation,3);
    setChildIndex(guiding,4);
    setChildIndex(yourb,1);
    setChildIndex(game,2);
}
}

function m3innovateClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
var gameout3Tween:Tween = new Tween(game, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 1, 0, 1, true);
var innovationin3Tween:Tween = new Tween(innovation, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 0, 1, 1, true);
innovationin3Tween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, innovation3Play);
function innovation3Play (event:TweenEvent):void{
    game.chess.gotoAndStop(1);
    innovation.innovate.gotoAndPlay(2);
    setChildIndex(innovation,4);
    setChildIndex(guiding,1);
    setChildIndex(yourb,2);
    setChildIndex(game,3);
}
}

function m3yourbClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
var gameout4Tween:Tween = new Tween(game, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 1, 0, 1, true);
var yourbin4Tween:Tween = new Tween(yourb, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 0, 1, 1, true);
yourbin4Tween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, yourb4Play);
function yourb4Play (event:TweenEvent):void{
    game.chess..gotoAndStop(1);
    yourb.industry.gotoAndPlay(2);
    setChildIndex(innovation,2);
    setChildIndex(guiding,3);
    setChildIndex(yourb,4);
    setChildIndex(game,1);
}
}

function m4oceanClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
var yourbout2Tween:Tween = new Tween(yourb, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 1, 0, 1, true);
var guidingin4Tween:Tween = new Tween(guiding, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 0, 1, 1, true);
guiding.ocean.gotoAndPlay(2);
guidingin4Tween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, guiding4Play);
function guiding4Play (event:TweenEvent):void{
    yourb.industry.gotoAndStop(1);
    setChildIndex(innovation,3);
    setChildIndex(guiding,4);
    setChildIndex(yourb,1);
    setChildIndex(game,2);
}
}

function m4innovateClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
var yourbout3Tween:Tween = new Tween(yourb, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 1, 0, 1, true);
var innovationin4Tween:Tween = new Tween(innovation, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 0, 1, 1, true);
innovationin4Tween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, innovation4Play);
function innovation4Play (event:TweenEvent):void{
    yourb.industry.gotoAndStop(1);
    innovation.innovate.gotoAndPlay(2);
    setChildIndex(innovation,4);
    setChildIndex(guiding,1);
    setChildIndex(yourb,2);
    setChildIndex(game,3);
}
}

function m4gameClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
var yourbout4Tween:Tween = new Tween(yourb, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 1, 0, 1, true);
var gamein4Tween:Tween = new Tween(game, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 0, 1, 1, true);
gamein4Tween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, game4Play);
function game4Play (event:TweenEvent):void{
    yourb.industry.gotoAndStop(1);
    game.chess.gotoAndPlay(2);
    setChildIndex(innovation,1);
    setChildIndex(guiding,2);
    setChildIndex(yourb,3);
    setChildIndex(game,4);
}
}

function movetoGame(event:Event):void{
if(innovation.innovate.currentFrame == 200){
    var innovationoutTween:Tween = new Tween(innovation, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 1, 0, 1, true);
    var gameinTween:Tween = new Tween(game, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 0, 1, 1, true);
    gameinTween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, gamePlay);
    function gamePlay (event:TweenEvent):void{
        game.chess.gotoAndPlay(2);
        setChildIndex(innovation,1);
        setChildIndex(guiding,2);
        setChildIndex(yourb,3);
        setChildIndex(game,4);
    }
}
}

function movetoYourb(event:Event):void{
if(game.chess.currentFrame == 200){
    var gameoutTween:Tween = new Tween(game, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 1, 0, 1, true);
    var yourbinTween:Tween = new Tween(yourb, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 0, 1, 1, true);
    yourbinTween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, yourbPlay);
    function yourbPlay (event:TweenEvent):void{
        yourb.industry.gotoAndPlay(2);
        setChildIndex(innovation,2);
        setChildIndex(guiding,3);
        setChildIndex(yourb,4);
        setChildIndex(game,1);
    }
}
}

function movetoGuiding(event:Event):void{
if(yourb.industry.currentFrame == 200){
    var yourboutTween:Tween = new Tween(yourb, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 1, 0, 1, true);
    var guidinginTween:Tween = new Tween(guiding, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 0, 1, 1, true);
    guiding.ocean.gotoAndPlay(2);
    guidinginTween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, guidingPlay);
    function guidingPlay (event:TweenEvent):void{
        setChildIndex(innovation,3);
        setChildIndex(guiding,4);
        setChildIndex(yourb,1);
        setChildIndex(game,2);
    }
}
}

function movetoInnovation(event:Event):void{
if(guiding.ocean.currentFrame == 200){
    var guidingoutTween:Tween = new Tween(guiding, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 1, 0, 1, true);
    var innovationinTween:Tween = new Tween(innovation, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 0, 1, 1, true);
    innovationinTween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, innovationPlay);
    function innovationPlay (event:TweenEvent):void{
        innovation.innovate.gotoAndPlay(2);
        setChildIndex(innovation,4);
        setChildIndex(guiding,1);
        setChildIndex(yourb,2);
        setChildIndex(game,3);
    }
}
}
```

The Main file has no problems on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start off by checking what's going on with the symbol mc_main_holder in the library of your loaded swf's FLA. The stack trace clearly indicates that you are trying to access a property of an undefined variable in the first frame of that symbol:

```
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
at mpb_animated_rotator_fla::mc_main_holder_16/frame1()
```

The stack trace goes on to say that in frame 10 of mc_starter_holder symbol you are trying to play frame 1 of mc_main_holder and that's where it gets stuck:

```
at mpb_animated_rotator_fla::mc_starter_holder_1/frame10()
```

You can read more about interpreting the stack trace and understanding errors [here](http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/fixing-bugs-in-as3-introduction/).

Also, and unrelated, I noticed you have a syntax error:

```
function m3oceanClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
var gameout2Tween:Tween = new Tween(game, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 1, 0, 1, true);
var guidingin3Tween:Tween = new Tween(guiding, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 0, 1, 1, true);
guiding.ocean.gotoAndPlay(2);
guidingin3Tween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, guiding3Play);
function guiding3Play (event:TweenEvent):void{
    game.chess..gotoAndStop(1);
    setChildIndex(innovation,3);
    setChildIndex(guiding,4);
    setChildIndex(yourb,1);
    setChildIndex(game,2);
}
}
```

7th line down reads "game.chess..gotoAndStop(1);". you have a double .. there.

Good luck!